# Why is my second rtags-server not working as expected?

Tags: c++, rtags

servers for two repositories in my machine. These two repos are actually the same git repository but I cloned it twice in my local file system.

The 1st rtags-server works as expected, but when the 2nd rtags-server starts, both rtags-servers print error messages like:

```
Running with 16 jobs, using args: -ferror-limit=50 -fspell-checking -Wno-unknown-warning-option
Includepaths: "-isystem" /usr/local/clang+llvm-10.0.1/lib/clang/10.0.1/include/
Restoring /home/chu/2nd/repo/ ..........................
```

Did anyone meet this error before? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think rtags is intended to support multiple rtags servers for the same user and host.  I have multiple git repositories and only one rtags server.  That one rtags server monitors for changes in all my git repositories and reindexes files when a C++ file changes in *any* repo.

Comment: Thanks! Will the multiple repos conflict with each other? For example, I cloned one repo multiple times to work on multiple branches in parallel. Is the Rtags server able to handle the difference? I am new to rtags internals, so I’m curious whether it is able to be that smart.

Comment: @DachuanHuang I don't know.  I usually clone from a central repository on another host and rtags works fine.  I don't usually clone from one host to the same host, but I suspect that would work too.